# Comma-separated string in IN clause of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to pass a variable in WHERE IN clause of oracle sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462415/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-where-in-clause-of-oracle-sql)

I have a column `Prefix` in my table `Tbl_Prefix` with value as string separated by comma like this:

```
'aaa','bbb','ccc'
```

I have an employee table `Tbl_Employee` like this:

```
Empno Prefix
------------
1000  aaa
2000  eee
3000  ccc
4000  aaa
5000  ddd
```

I need to use this prefix in the `IN` portion of my `WHERE` clause in this query:

```
Select * 
from Tbl_Employee  
where Tbl_Employee.Prefix  in (select  Tbl_Prefix.prefix 
                               from Tbl_Prefix 
                               where Tbl_Prefix.flag = 'y')
```

The inner select query `select Tbl_Prefix.prefix from Tbl_Prefix where Tbl_Prefix.flag='y'` has the result `'aaa','bbb','ccc'`

How to use this string in the 'IN' clause so that I will get a proper result?

Comment: By the way, if those values are stored in you database like that, you should seriously reconsider your database design. Create a child table that contains a record for each of the comma separated values for each parent record. If the data is dumped like this, create a job to process the raw data to a structure like that. With a proper table structure, you will only need a relatively simple inner join.

Comment: Actually this table column is inserted upon user selecting a set of prefix from listbox.List box is populated as aaa,bbb,ccc etc from another table.Whe user select some prefix,I store them as a string in my prefix table column.I need to use this user selected prefix,in the sql query.How can I store this selected prefix in Prefix table ?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't do that. Creat a data bucket/link table and link aaa, bbb and ccc to its relevant relationship.

However, if you have to do it this way (change it if possible!), you'll have to create a dynamic SQL string and execute it. So, build the string from the select through the where and append the "Prefix" delimited string, then call `EXEC`.

So, you'll set:

`@sql = 'SELECT YOURSTUFF FROM YOURTABLE WHERE YOURCOLUMN IN ' + @prefix.` `@prefix` should be the column value (aaa,bbb,ccc) from tbl_Prefix you needed.

Once your string is built, `EXEC @sql`

Answer (score 0):

If those values are stored in you database like that, you should seriously reconsider your database design. Create a child table that contains a record for each of the comma separated values for each parent record.

For now, you can get away using `EXISTS` and `LIKE`, but this query will become slower soon if you got a lot of records.

```
select 
  * 
from 
  Tbl_Employee e
where 
  exists  
    (select * from 
       Tbl_Prefix x
    where
       x.flag = 'y' and
       x.prefix like '%''' + e.prefix + '''%') 
       -- Add quotes to prevent false matches
```